# SetImageResource random value not work

Tags: android, random

I want to get RANDOM value in my function, But n always equals 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //блок Random
    Log.d(Tag, "1");
    int NUM_IMAGES=7;
    int imageArr[] = new int[NUM_IMAGES];
    Log.d(Tag, "2");
    imageArr[0] = R.drawable.image1;
    imageArr[1] = R.drawable.image2;
    imageArr[2] = R.drawable.image3;
    imageArr[3] = R.drawable.image4;
    imageArr[4] = R.drawable.image5;
    imageArr[5] = R.drawable.image6;
    imageArr[6] = R.drawable.image7;

    Log.d(Tag, "3");
    int n = (int)Math.random()*NUM_IMAGES;
    Log.d(Tag, "n="+n);
    image.setImageResource(imageArr[n]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`(int) Math.random()` is executed first and will always return 0. Then multiplying NUM_IMAGES by 0 still returns 0.

You should add brackets around your expression so the conversion to `int` will be done after the multiplication :

```
int n = (int) (Math.random()*NUM_IMAGES);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read [here](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php), the priority of `type cast` is more than that of multiplication. Also the priority of `()`(bracket) is higher than that of type cast. So the right way might be to put multiplication in bracket so that multiplication happens before casting. Something like:

```
int n = (int)(Math.random() * NUM_IMAGES);
```

Notice the brackets. Hope this helps.